# Background image loading slowly

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a site utilizing a background image that resizes to the window's size. This is achieved by placing an `<img>` in the body, and some custom CSS ( [Technique #2](http://css-tricks.com/3458-perfect-full-page-background-image/) ).

I use a simple conditional statement in the header to determine which image to display:

```
<?php if (is_single(array(11,24,26,28,30,36))) : ?>
    <img src="http://www.lookingglassstudio.ca/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/weddingsbg.jpg" class="bg" />
<?php else : ?>
    <img src="http://www.lookingglassstudio.ca/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/stylingbg.jpg" class="bg" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

My problem is, the image reloads every time I refresh or navigate somewhere else. This results in a flash of white. See the website [here!](http://www.lookingglassstudio.ca/)

I reckon the php script calls the image each time, resulting in the 'flash'.

Any way around this? Ways to make the image cache and not reload each time?

**EDIT**

I believe the issue is a FOUC problem. Will flash the background color (default white) when refreshed, causing flashes. FOUC fixes don't seem to help.

Issue occurs even with PHP conditional statement removed. Issue occurs when `<img>` is changed to background-image.

Comment: I see no `?` in your question... where is the question?

Comment: @SalmanA: You're correct that the question was missing after Sirwilliam's first edit, I've added it back in, maybe you can provide an answer.

Comment: @Sirwilliam85: are you testing in IE?

Comment: I was experiencing the problem in Safari and Chrome, but my client experienced it in IE, which I cannot replicate yet.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this question a while ago but hoped you'd get an answer that worked for you.

Seeing as nothing has worked for you so far, I have one piece of advice: When you save your .jpg files (the big background images), you might want to save them in "progressive" format if possible.

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG
>
> There is also an interlaced "Progressive JPEG" format, in which data
>   is compressed in multiple passes of progressively higher detail. This
>   is ideal for large images that will be displayed while downloading
>   over a slow connection, allowing a reasonable preview after receiving
>   only a portion of the data. However, progressive JPEGs are not as
>   widely supported, and even some software which does support them (such
>   as some versions of Internet Explorer) only displays the image once it
>   has been completely downloaded.

Instead of loading the image in a line from top to bottom, it will instead "progressively" become clearer and less pixelated, so you won't see the FOUC as much with the background visible behind it.

Besides this, make sure you provide a background color that won't heavily contrast the image, and try to compress the file size as much as your design can withstand.

Comment: Most modern browsers support Progressive JPEGs/interlaced GIFs and they will render them progressively *if the image is in the foreground*; background images won't be rendered progressively, they just... appear.

Comment: Can you explain? How does the browser know the image is "in the foreground", and what do you mean by that? Not sure if this is relevant, but OP is using an `<img>` tag and not a CSS background. Reference would be great if you have it.

Comment: I mean `<img src='foo.jpg'>` versus `<div style='background: url(foo.jpg);'>`. I need clarification from OP too; the question is not clear and tampered-with.

Comment: As far as "tampered with", you can always review the edit history and "tamper" with it yourself it if you see fit, but as far as which method is being used, I think it's clear from the question.

Comment: Ah... I now see the website in question. Seems like foreground/background is not the issue. I've posted an answer.

Comment: This is valuable information, and much appreciated! I will try this out!

Comment: I did end up trying a similar background color, and the client is now happy with the results. I have figured out a few ways to optimize, but I'll place an answer below...

Comment: ps. I appreciate patience with my "tampering", I'm new to stackoverflow and still figuring out protocol! :)

Comment: @Sirwilliam85: it was me who said that the question was *tampered*, didn't realize it was a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I checked your website and found everything to be working as expected. When the browser requests the page with an empty cache, the image will take a few seconds to download. When you navigate to any other page of the website, the browser fetches the image from the cache -- I do not see any flash on FF4, nor I see the browser requesting the stylingbg/weddingsbg image more than once per session.

If you notice that the image is loaded every time you visit the page then probably your browser cache is disabled (or incorrectly configured). The server does not seem to send the `Expires` header; explicitly specifying an the expires header might help in certain cases.

Also note that some browsers request all resources *from the scratch* when you hit refresh. Modern browsers (I checked on FF4) will send an `If-Modified-Since` header, a sensible server will only return a *Not Modified* response hence no flickering.

Apart from that, I suggest that you add a CSS background color to your page that matches the tone of the background image. This helps in situations when images are disabled or take long time to load. Also consider @Wesley's suggestion about using progressive images. Your current image loads from top to bottom. You can improve the user's experience by converting the image to progressive JPEG.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS instead.

```
<style>
body.weddings {
    background-image: url('http://www.lookingglassstudio.ca/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/weddingsbg.jpg');
}

body.styling {
    background-image: url('http://www.lookingglassstudio.ca/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/stylingbg.jpg');
}
</style>
```

Then in PHP:

```
<?php if (is_single(array(11,24,26,28,30,36))) : ?>
<body class="weddings">
<?php else : ?>
<body class="styling">
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This is a good solution, and it might work actually. The only problem is, I have a @ media screen type (as seen above in technique 2) to keep the image from sizing too small. This requires an img, rather than a background image. So I was hoping for a way to keep the img from reloading on every refresh. I may try your solution though.

Comment: I believe the problem is a FOUC issue. There is a flash of unstyled content (the background color of the img.bg). So far the only solution I can come up with is to change the background color of the img class to something close. This is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered the source of the issue, and I appreciate previous comments as they have helped immensely!

The problem is Wordpress 3.2, and underlying conflicts with jQuery. These conflicts result in the return of the dreaded FOUC in webkit browsers and sometimes IE.

There is no perfect solution, but all three of the following have greatly helped:

1.) Placing an empty script call right before the javascript call helps 'kickstart' the stylesheet, greatly reduces duration of FOUC white flash.

```
<script type=”text/javascript”></script>
```

2.) Downgrading to jQuery 1.4.4. Found [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-fix-the-flash-on-page-load-32x). Evidently the issue is with newer versions of jQuery and WP 3.2 conflicting. A way to do this without affecting admin functions is to add the following to the functions.php file in your theme:

```
    // Downgrade to jQuery 1.4.4 in order to support jQuery Tools
    function downgrade_jquery() {
    global $wp_scripts;

    // We want to use version 1.4.4 of jQuery, but it may break something in the admin so we only load it on the actual site.
    if ( !is_admin() ) :
            wp_deregister_script('jquery');
            wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js', false, '1.4.4');
    endif;
    }
    add_action( 'wp_head', downgrade_jquery() );
```

3.) Utilizing a similar background color to match your image, as recommended above by Wesley Murch and Salman A. I haven't tried progressive JPEG format yet, but I imagine this would help as well.

The combination seems to almost eliminate the FOUC for Wordpress 3.2, and provides a solution, at least until developers eliminate the problem in future versions.

I'd like to alter the title to more accurately represent the problem I was facing.